# jOOQ - execute postgres user defined function with refcursor

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm having some problems with executing functions that takes and returns postgres `refcursor` in jooq. I have no idea how to approach with instantiation the `ref`, which is `Result<Record>` and how to loop through the records I should get from the function I want to execute.

Let's say I have a following function in postgres (postgres 9.5):

```
create or replace function foo_cursor(name character varying, ref refcursor)
returns refcursor
as $func$
begin
  open ref for
    select id, first_name, last_name
    from students
    where first_name = name;
  return ref;
end
$func$ 
language plpgsql;
```

And in postgres I'm executing in like that:

```
begin;
select foo_cursor('Konrad', 'my_cursor');
fetch all in "my_cursor";
commit;
```

The function has to stay the same - it returns `refcursor` and takes `refcursor`.

And I want to execute it in jOOQ:

```
Routines.fooCursor(configuration, "Konrad", ____);
```

But I don't know what to put inside the `____`, which takes `Result<Record>`. I tried something like:

```
Result<Record> records = DSL.using(configuration).newResult();
```

but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ supports the `refcursor` result type (or `OUT` parameter) in PostgreSQL, but not the `IN` parameter type, which is really a bit of a quirk, given that it pretends to be a pseudo type for an identifier. If you can overload your function to this:

```sql
create or replace function foo_cursor(name character varying)
returns refcursor
as $func$
declare
  ref refcursor;
begin
  open ref for
    select id, first_name, last_name
    from students
    where first_name = name;
  return ref;
end
$func$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Then, jOOQ will be able to call the function. There's no need for jOOQ (or you, when using jOOQ) to define the resulting cursor name.

You may, however, need to run the function call inside of a transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked that, but when I use `Routines.fooCursor(configuration)` it gives me `DataAccessException` with message `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist`. I tried to instantiate the `refcursor` with `declare ref refcursor := 'mycursor';` but then I would get the same error that tells me  the `mycursor` does not exist.

Comment: @kodi1911: Are you running your jOOQ code in a transaction?

Comment: running it inside `context.transactionResult(config -> Routines.fooCursor(config).getValues("first_name", String.class));` does the work. Thank you for your help. You're great :)

Comment: Indeed, I vaguely remembered transactions being a requirement when calling refcursor functions from JDBC clients... Thanks for the nice words :)